# How can I view the bounces after a specific event in Google Analytics?

Tags: events, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I've set up a bunch of Events in Google Analytics to track my new user signup process.  I've got a modal window that pops up with the form, and I have events for form show, form click_submit and form success, as well as an event when a field is marked as invalid (I use some javascript validation).

The question I want to answer is How many users abandon the form after a specific field is shown as invalid?  I am not using virtual page views (I think that since this is a modal window, virtual page view might not make sense) so I can't set up a funnel report in Google Analytics.  Also, the Event Flow report isn't super useful since the user might abandon the form after 1 attempt, or 3 attempts with invalid data, and I can't account for all possible paths between two events in that report.  Ideally what I'd like to do is set a start point "ShowForm" event, and an endpoint, "FormSuccess" and see all the paths between these, and figure out at what intermediate event people abandon the form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Peterw**, for this type of analysis, much better choise is [Clicktale](http://www.clicktale.com/) which provides built-in functionality for exactly those questions. It would require quite a bit of coding and changes to your current GA implementation, but it's doable. I have done that, and still think Clicktale or any [similar tool](http://spyrestudios.com/usability-conversion-analysis-tools/) is easier to use and worth the money.